how to print loss from Yolov8n : model.val()?
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
metrics=model.val(data='data.yaml', split='test')

how to access the class loss or box loss from the variable metrics?
I can only access the following variables but I need either box or cls loss.
how to get it
# Validate the model

metrics = model.val()  # no arguments needed, dataset and settings remembered

metrics.box.map    # map50-95 
metrics.box.map50  # map50
metrics.box.map75  # map75
metrics.box.maps   # a list contains map50-95 of each category`

